# How Can I Write Data From SerialPort Using "LIS01A2" Nuget Package

Tags: c#, serial-port, astm

Hi I Want To Make Communication With Some Labratory Analyzors And I Researching So Much I Found Some Helps Like That "LIS01A2" Nuget packaje I Finally Can Receive Data From Machine In this Code :

This Is Sub For OnReceiveString EventHandler in LIS01A2

```
_lowLevelConnection.OnReceiveString += lowLevelConnection_OnReceiveString;
```

And :

```
private void lowLevelConnection_OnReceiveString(object Sender, LISConnectionReceivedDataEventArgs e)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show("Received");
            string received = null;
            received = e.ReceivedData;   
            SaveDataToDataLayer(received);

        }
```

With That EventHandler And My SaveDataToDateLayer I Can Receive Data and Save That In My Data base(From "Sysmex XP300" Machine).

But When I Want To Make communication with Another device like "Biolis 24i" or "Cobas e411" I can't receive any message And think I need to Send some Order message To Device For answering Me and sending me the result Data.

I know About  and  Answer of device.

I have Some question know :

Is that necessary To make app with "LIS01A2" Nuget package or I can send and receive messages From devices With just an App with serial port Comunication ??

How can I send data from "LIS01A2" nuget package to my device ??

And I need Some help with making Communication with labratory Devices supporting ASTM.

Comment: I've removed the "lis" tag as it has nothing to do with your question. It's for the "longest increasing subsequence problem".